Name of horror/thriller where guy breaks in and kills husband but wife fights to stay alive
In this movie it starts off with with a voicemail from the wife's mom I think talking about the couples son who's with her. I'm pretty sure his name is Jack and as the voicemail is playing you see boots walking around the house tampering with windows and the alarm and phones then he puts his feet up on a table and turns on the TV.
The couple comes home and are going to have sex I think. But the wife wants to shower first. So the husband goes downstairs and drinks some alcohol and plays gold while listening to his record. The killer sees him and kills him.
The wife calls to the husband and I think she goes downstairs and sees his body.
The rest is kinda a blur. But the end she got a number from the sheriff of a cop and when she calls the number after she stabs the killer a phone rings in the house. She realizes the cop was the killer and in pretty sure he kills her. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Home Sweet Home (2013) http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2348394/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt

This matches Home Sweet Home (2013). You can see the answerphone scene at the start of the film, and the cop was indeed the killer in the paper overalls.



